# In integration by parts of $\int uv$, why do we not consider the constant of integration formed by $\int v$ in $\int (u'\int v)$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

In the integration by parts equation $\int uv = u\int v - \int (u'\int v)$:

Consider $\int v = g(x)+c$. So the above equation becomes $\int uv = u\int v - \int u'.(g(x)+c)$. But in integration of say, $\ln x$ as shown below, this constant is neglected. Why?

$ \int\ln x.dx = \log x\int dx - \int(\frac{d}{dx}\log x.\int dx).dx $

$ \int\ln x.dx = \log x\int dx - \int (x\frac{1}{x}).dx$ (Step 2)

$ \int\ln x.dx = \log x\int dx - \int dx $

$ \int\ln x.dx = x\log x - x + C$

$ \int\ln x.dx = x(\log x -1) + C $

Why is it $x.\frac {1}{x}$ in step 2 and not $x.(\frac{1}{x} + C)$? Or will it make no difference either way?

Comment: It is absorbed by the constant of the other integral. After all, when you have 2 arbitrary constants added together, you could just give them a new name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Morally, adding a constant should *not* affect the result. We might try intuiting an reason (and you should regardless), but proof is a good way to settle these doubts.

Let $V'(x) = v(x)$ (choose an antiderivative of $v$). Then $$\begin{align}&\frac{d}{dx}\left[u(x)(V(x)+c) - \int u'(s)(V(s)+c)\,ds\right] =\\[2ex] &= u'(x)(V(x)+c)+u(x)v(x) -u'(x)(V(x)+c) \\[2ex] &=\fbox {$u(x)v(x)$}\end{align}$$

Where $c$ is an arbitrary real number. So no, choosing a different primitive/antiderivative of $v$ does not change the result of integration by parts, as we hoped.

Comment: Another perspective on the same answer is to see directly that, in your notation, $u(x)(V(x) + c) - \int u'(s)(V(s) + c)\mathrm ds = \bigl(u(x)V(x) - \int u'(s)V(s)\mathrm ds\bigr) + (c u(x) - \int u'(s)c\mathrm ds)$ (where $\int = \int_a^x$ for some fixed $a$) differs from $u(x)V(x) - \int u'(s)V(s)\mathrm ds$ by $c u(x) - \int u'(s)c\mathrm ds = c u(a)$, which is constant.

Comment: @JadeNB I thought about going that way! In the end, to avoid mentioning definite integrals (which I would like, but I wanted to keep it in OP's language) and also to avoid the ambiguity with indefinite integrals I chose to differentiate. The poor-definedness of the indefinite integral gets hidden that way ;)

Comment: @JadeNB On second thought, the alternative view also allows for indefinite integrals, just say that $\int u'(s)c\,ds = u(x)c+d$ in your last expression.

Comment: That's a good point; I just thought that viewing it as a definite integral would help to see *why* $c u(x) - \int u'(s)c\,\mathrm ds$ was constant.  I think that your argument is probably at least as clear, though.